# failing to compare space in a string

Tags: c++, string, atoi

I'm making a program which is getting inputs from the user, while each input contains ints delimited with spaces. e.g "2 3 4 5".

I implemented the atoi function well, but, whenever I try to run on the string and "skip" on the spaces I get a runtime error:

```
for(int i=0, num=INIT; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==' ')
            continue;

        string tmp;
        for(int j=i; input[j]!=' '; j++)
        {
            //add every char to the temp string
            tmp+=input[j];

            //means we are at the end of the number. convert to int
            if(input[i+1]==' ' || input[i+1]==NULL)
            {
                num=m_atoi(tmp);
                i=j;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the line 'if(input[i+1]==' '.....' I get an exception.
Basically, I'm trying to insert just "2 2 2 2".
I realized that whenever I try to compare a real space in the string and ' ', the exception raises.

I tried to compare with the ASCII value of space which is 32 but that failed too.
Any ideas?

Comment: It is likely that `i+1` exceeds the length of the string.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to figure out why.

Comment: You could do this very easily and with a lot less code with a stringstream.

Comment: There will surely be a problem accessing `input[i+1]` when i equals 3

Comment: oo thanks!!! i realized when i do cin into string, it stop recieving chars after the space...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check for the end of the string in your main loop:

```
for(int j=i; input[j]!=' '; j++)
```

should be:

```
for(int j=i; input[j]!=0 && input[j]!=' '; j++)
```

Also, don't use `NULL` for the NUL char. You should use `'\0'` or simply `0`. The macro `NULL` should be used only for pointers.

That said, it may be easier in your case to just use `strtol` or `istringstream` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not an answer to the question.

but two big for a comment.

You should note the C++ stream library automatically reads and decodes int from a space separated stream:

```
int main()
{
    int value;
    std::cin >> value; // Reads and ignores space then stores the next int into `value`
}
```

Thus to read multiple ints just put it in a loop:

```
   while(std::cin >> value)   // Loop will break if user hits ctrl-D or ctrl-Z
   {                          // Or a normal file is piped to the stdin and it is finished.
        // Use value
   }
```

To read a single line. That contains space separated values just read the line into a string (convert this to a stream then read the values.

```
   std::string line;
   std::getline(std::cin, line);            // Read a line into a string
   std::stringstream linestream(line);      // Convert string into a stream

   int value;
   while(linestream >> value)               // Loop as above.
   {
        // Use Value
   }
```